# Get attributes from an XML tag using Python

Tags: python, xml, csv

I am trying to grab the attributes from an XML tag so I can get the correct data and place it in a CSV file

I have attempted to find some answers, but have found nothing definitive other than how to grab that tag itself, or get the attributes using another language.

Here is what a line from the XML file will look like:

```
<item id="16" class="ItemClass" status="closed" 
opened="2008-07-14T22:31:10Z" closed="2008-07-14T23:45:08Z" 
url="www.google.com"/>
```

The Tag is "item"
The attributes are "id", "class", "status", "opened", "closed", "url"

I can get the tag name, and the items inside the tag `(<tag>item inside tag</tag>)` using a method found [here](http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/how-to-parse-and-convert-xml-to-csv-using-python/):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

item_head = []
item = []

[...]

name = item.find('item').tag
item_head.append(name)

name = item.find('item').text
item.append(name)
```

But I want to get that ATTRIBUTES, not the tag.

I can easily write the header of the file since the items will always contain the same information. So, this would look like:

```
item_head.append('id')
item_head.append('class')
item_head.append('status')
...and so on...
```

But I don't know how to grab the other information, such as id="16"

End result should be something like this:

```
id, class, status, opened, closed, url
16, ItemClass, closed, 2008-07-14T22:31:10Z, 2008-07-14T23:45:08Z, www.google.com
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [xml.etree.ElementTree.Element](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=elementtree#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element) also has an `attrib` property, which is a dictionary containing the element’s attributes

```
>>> item.attrib['id']
'16'
```

Comment: Well, that was simple. =) Thank you!